# Removed class seems to be still there

Tags: jquery, removeclass, toggleclass

I have a button that switches classes of a menue using this script:

```
$('#btn-menue').click(function () {
$('#menue').toggleClass('hoverbutton clickbutton');
}
```

The class I am starting with is ".hoverbutton" and the toggling seems to work (checked this with firebug). But when the active class is ".clickbutton", *this* script although works (and although the console output is clickbutton):

```
$(".hoverbutton").on({
    mouseenter:  function () {
    console.log($(this).attr('class'));
  }
```

So where is my error in reasoning? IMHO the script on ".hoverbutton" shouldn´t work when the class is removed.
THX for any help.

Comment: Where's the closing brackets for the functions? Are you missing some of the code?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because the events are bound on page load, when the element *does* have the `hoverbutton` class. The fact that the class is removed later in the page lifecycle bears no relevance; the event is already bound to the element. To do what you require you need to use event delegation. Try this:

```
$(document).on('.hoverbutton', 'mouseenter', function () {
    console.log($(this).attr('class'));
});
```

Note that I used `document` simply as an example. In production code you should use the closest static element to the `.hoverbutton` element that's in the DOM on page load.

Answer (score 0):

Rory's answer is almost right. He used parameters order from old delegate method

jQuery 1.4.3+:

```
$( elements ).delegate( selector, events, data, handler );
```

jQuery 1.7+:

```
$( elements ).on( events, [selector,] [data,] handler );
```

Fixed example:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.hoverbutton', function () {
    console.log($(this).attr('class'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the class doesn't remove the event listening you have already added when the page loaded.  If you want to remove an event listener in jQuery then you need to use .off()

you could for example:

```
$('#btn-menue').click(function () {
    $('#menue').toggleClass('hoverbutton clickbutton');
    $('#menue).off("mouseenter");
}
```